# SUM n rows of each group with ORDER BY and LIMIT where the LIMIT is based off of another table

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-5.6, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a requirement to build a leaderboard of users of a fantasy football game. 
The simplified database of the game is as follows:

- `users` have `squad_players` in `squads` for each `matches` (related by *transfer_period*)
- `players` have `match_points` for each `matches`
- `squad_players` have **position**, **priority**. The **priority** is the order of substitutions if a `squad_players` does not appear in a `matches`
- `squads` have `formations` which determine the maximum number of players to select from of each **position** ordered by **priority**

The database is **MySQL 5.6** and the maximum number of `users` is **10K**.

I am able to inner join (in order) `squad_players`, `squads`, `matches`, `match_points` to get the point of each `squad_players` who played (`players` who didn't play have no `match_points`).

I am struggling to **SUM** the points of **x** `squad_players` of each `squads` where **x** is in `formations` and determined by **position** of the **squad_players**.

I have tried to modify versions of **Top n-rows with group by** with correlated subqueries but without success.

What should my approach be here?

---

My **Expected Output** is something like this

```
|---------|-----------|------------|----------|
| User ID |  SQUAD ID | POSITION   |  POINTS  |  
|---------|-----------|------------|----------|
|   12    |    34     | defender   |    12    |
|---------|-----------|------------|----------|
|   12    |    34     | forward    |    2     |
|---------|-----------|------------|----------|
|  117    |    31     | midfielder |    5     |
|---------|-----------|------------|----------|
```

**Notes**:

- I must add the outputs may not reflect the problem statement.
- If you look into the [Sample Dataset Link](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1qG2cR4Il4IAEZyKYKeOGbP0D3Isqj4_v), you will find a view
  named `normalized_squad_player_points` that is the denormalized table I want to work with to create different stats.

Final Output for the leaderboard will be something like this

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      User ID        |       Points     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         |         34       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          56         |         32       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          117        |         31       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

---

**Additional information**

- [SQL Fiddle link to schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4559cd).
- [Link to exported Schema and Sample Dataset](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1qG2cR4Il4IAEZyKYKeOGbP0D3Isqj4_v).
- I'm open to modifying table definitions if necessary.
- [Pastebin link to `squads` and `match_points` inserts](https://pastebin.com/AgnWgArU).

Comment: It would be much better if you provided the `CREATE TABLE` statements, sample data (INSERT a few rows) and wanted result set. Reading your question, it is not very clear which which names refer to tables and which to columns

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ , thanks for the suggesstion. Added a SQLfiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4559cd) for the schema

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ , added the expected outputs. But I must add the outputs may not reflect the problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I ended up implementing was to break up the query into simpler ones based on the different permutations of the `positions` and `formations`. I also needed to add several tables to store intermediate results. I ran all the queries (around 42) in a transaction.

This worked out pretty well and completed in reasonable time without overloading the server resources.

I guess trying to do it in one giant query was a bad decision from the beginning. Breaking it up into smaller queries allowed the process to be maintainable and flexible.